# flexdashboard isolate table for child Rmd

Tags: r, shiny, flexdashboard

I'm trying to incorporate an Rmd I have been using into a flexdashboard. I'm curious if it is possible to isolate an uploaded file and use it as-is rather than writing a bunch of reactive functions. If this is my template, is it possible to get a static object named `df` that the child document can go ahead and run with?

````
---
title: "help"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: columns
---

```{r}
fileInput("data", "select data")

df <- isolate(input$data)
```

```{r, child="some_code.Rmd"}
```
````

My real example does something completely different but let's say `some_code.Rmd` looks like this:

````
---
title: "some code"
output: html_document
---

```{r packages, include=FALSE}
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = FALSE, message = FALSE)
library(tidyverse)
```

The data looks like this:
```{r}
as_tibble(df)
```

The numeric data can be summarized with the following means
```{r}
df |> 
  summarise(across(where(is.numeric), mean)) |> 
  gather()
```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This ended up working:

`knitr::knit()` + `markdown::markdownToHTML()` + `HTML()` ---> `renderUI()`

````
---
title: "help"
runtime: shiny
output: 
  flexdashboard::flex_dashboard:
    orientation: rows
---

Sidebar {.sidebar}
==============================================
```{r file-input}
fileInput("data", "select data")
```

Row
==============================================

```{r knit-child}
observeEvent(input$data, {
  df <- isolate(read.csv(input$data$datapath))
  new_env <- list2env(list(df = df))
  
  output$res <- renderUI({
    knitr::knit("some_code.Rmd", quiet = TRUE, envir = new_env) |> 
      markdown::markdownToHTML() |> 
      HTML()
  })
})

uiOutput("res")
```
````